# json Data with POST requests in Python doesn't arrive

Tags: php, python, json, post, httprequest

I like to build a small REST Interface to connect PYTHON with PHP.
After some hours of google I ended with nearly copy&paste code from several discussion-boards:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://spidercontrol.ilumiweb.local/helge/voltage'

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
data = {'value': '7.4', 'decay_time': '300'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

This should send the data as json via POST to the given url.This is where it's sended to:

```
<?php

  echo "Method: \t".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\r\n";
  print_r(getallheaders());
  echo "Post:";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "Get:";
  print_r($_GET);
  exit;
?>
```

But there is nothing in the $_POST data:

```
Method:         POST
Array
(
    [Host] => spidercontrol.ilumiweb.local
    [Content-Length] => 37
    [Content-type] => application/json
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, compress
    [Accept] => text/plain
    [User-Agent] => python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Windows/7
)
Post:Array
(
)
Get:Array
(
)
```

If I use the same code, but remove the headers=headers information but data=data it works well. Did someone know why?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP `$_POST` only contains form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded POST bodies).

To get JSON data you'll need to read the request body directly using [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) instead:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```